# How to get SharePoint 2010 List Items into .Net Application in another domain externally

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I have a public facing SharePoint 2010 site and I want to access using C#. Net Application externally which is in another domain.

Can anyone please explain step by step how to get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using two ways:

- Consume SharePoint Lists.asmx from your C# Application.
- Or use ListData.svc, which provides REST interface for getting list information.

Here is a sample for latter: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010-for-listdata-svc-part-2/